# How to get s2i to connect to a private NuGet feed

Tags: nuget, openshift, s2i

I have OpenShift set up to build a ASP.NET Core application. I've succeeded in configuring OpenShift so it pulls in the latest source code. I see in the logs that it starts to build, but it immediately stops on the restore step.

OpenShift doesn't have access to our private NuGet feeds.

I know I can add credentials to the NuGet.config file, but that would mean committing sensitive information to the repository, which we don't want.

I've tried adding Input Secrets, as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-during-build). I did this by creating a secret that contains the NuGet.config contents and adding the secret to my BuildConfig. I still get the same error (a HTTP 401).

Can I somehow tell OpenShift how to connect to the private NuGet feeds? Maybe using the secrets feature perhaps?

Comment: Can you share the way you attached the secret to the BC?

Comment: @ptrk I just edited the yaml and added secrets > secret > name: ... As mentioned in the docs.

Comment: The secrets can be normally mounted as folders with files, so if NuGet expects them in a specific location, that's where you need to put them. As @abn mentioned below, it the ``destinationDir`` parameter (see the docs).

Answer (score 1):

In the case of nuget configuration, you will need to specify where the `NuGet.Config` build input secret gets mounted into. This can be done by setting the `destinationDir` parameter to a valid [configuration location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses).

As for being able to add the config file in your repository itself, you can do this by making use of environment variable references in the config, for example `<add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%NUGET_REPO_PASSWORD%" />`. The `NUGET_REPO_PASSWORD` environment variable can then be configured in your build configuration and value referenced from an OpenShift secret.

Hope this gets you going. If all else fails, you can definitely override the s2i assemble script with your own by adding an executable script at `.s2i/bin/assemble` of your project repository.